# display an ImageView 'On-Top' of a camera view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I have an iOS app that is scanning a barcode using the camera everything works great as far as that is concerned. But I want to place dotted rectangle on the screen for the user to 'aim' the camera.
When I run the app in the simulator the rectangle shows up just fine, but when I run on the device I don't see the rectangle.
I have tried the bringSubviewToFront method but doesn't appear to be working on the device.

The following code is in the ViewDidLoad:

```
 // Draw a rectangle for aiming the camera
        let renderer = UIGraphicsImageRenderer(size:CGSize(width:500, height: 200))

        let img = renderer.image {ctx in
            ctx.cgContext.setFillColor(UIColor.clear.cgColor)
            ctx.cgContext.setStrokeColor(UIColor.red.cgColor)
            ctx.cgContext.setLineWidth(7)

            // Make it a dashed line - comment out for a solid line
            ctx.cgContext.setLineDash(phase:0, lengths: [20])

            let rectangle = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 200)
            ctx.cgContext.addRect(rectangle)
            ctx.cgContext.drawPath(using: .fillStroke)
        }

        // Create an imageView to hold the rectangle image
        let myImageView = UIImageView(image: img)
        myImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 147, y: 298, width: 500, height: 250)
        myImageView.layer.cornerRadius = 7

        cameraView.addSubview(myImageView)

        // Add constraints using an extension
        myImageView.anchor(top: cameraView.topAnchor,
                           leading: cameraView.leadingAnchor,
                           bottom: cameraView.bottomAnchor,
                           trailing: cameraView.trailingAnchor,
                           padding: .init(top: 250, left: 100, bottom: 250, right: 100),
                           size: .init(width: 500, height: 250))

        // Bring the rectangle to the front
        cameraView.bringSubviewToFront(myImageView)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to add an image for the captureSession you need to create a

```
AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer
```

otherwise you can't do it if you need to call the camera services for taking ***pictures***.

first create the variables and the view

```
var captureSession: AVCaptureSession!
        var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!

        let overlay: UIImageView = {
            let overlay = UIImageView(frame: CGRect.zero)
            overlay.image = UIImage(named: "makedCamera")
            overlay.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleToFill
            overlay.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            return overlay
        }()
```

after you make all your capture session code

```
previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        previewLayer.frame = view.layer.bounds
        previewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
        view.addSubview(overlay)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            overlay.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            overlay.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            overlay.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            overlay.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor)
            ])

        captureSession.startRunning()
```

simply ***overlay is the image***

```
view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
        view.addSubview(overlay)
```

***full Code:***

```
{
        super.viewDidLoad()

        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        self.title = ""

        captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

        guard let videoCaptureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: .video) else { return }
        let videoInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput

        do {
            videoInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoCaptureDevice)
        } catch {
            return
        }

        if (captureSession.canAddInput(videoInput)) {
            captureSession.addInput(videoInput)
        } else {
            failed()
            return
        }

        let metadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()

        if (captureSession.canAddOutput(metadataOutput)) {
            captureSession.addOutput(metadataOutput)

            metadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue.main)
            metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [.qr]
        } else {
            failed()
            return
        }

        previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSession)
        previewLayer.frame = view.layer.bounds
        previewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
        view.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
        view.addSubview(overlay)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            overlay.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor),
            overlay.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),
            overlay.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            overlay.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor)
            ])

        captureSession.startRunning()
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at this later today

Comment: you're welcome, mark as correct if this solves/help your issue

Comment: Jose, forgive me I'm a little confused, pretty new to this stuff.  I already have the previewLayer and capture session code and am currently able to scan a barcode without issue. My original code above is creating a rectangle and image view with its constraints, I'm just not sure how to get that image view to show 'on-top' of the image the camera is displaying?

Comment: no worries, check on my answer in this part of the code  **NSLayoutConstraint.activate([** that's how you set the constraints to set your image on the screen. top anchor == top of the screen, leading anchor == left of the screen, trailing anchor == right of the screen

Comment: them it says equal to: that means equal to a part of the screen where you want to set them.
**view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor** view == the screen, safeareaLayoutGuide is the safe area for the iphone X, XR, XS max, top anchor == top of the screen

Comment: you can also add a constant if you want to separareted a bit 
equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 5) it means it will me separated by a constant of 5 top the top of the screen

Comment: Thanks Jose, I figured it out with your suggestion